Laravel calculating cron next date by expression that has more than 5 characters
I want to get the next date to run the cron from a given string like
$cronExpression = '00 00 05 *  * *';
$cron = CronExpression::factory($cronExpression);
$cron->getNextRunDate()

However, dragonmantank/cron-expression or mtdowling/cron-expression only support expressions with 5 characters, while my expression has at least 6 characters.
Does anyone have any recommendations on how to achieve this?
I tried to follow the solution from PHP - Get date of next crontab's run but it didn't work as I expected.

Did yo try the accepted answer in the same url?
